# why does my login form not work on internet explorer?

Tags: authentication, internet-explorer

I have a website running on my server. I use a classical symfony login form, with FOSUserBundle. The login pages works perfectly fine except for one user, who is using Internet Explorer (don't know which version) => he is the only user having this issue. Other users with Internet Explorer and using the same network did not have the issue at all.

When this user types his credentials on the login page (mail + password) and clicks on the submit button, nothing happens. The form submits and then the user is on the login page once again with nothing happening.

This client is connecting from his company network. And when he tries to login using another browser (Firefox), everything works fine and the login functions.

Besides, we tried to hard refresh the page on Internet Explorer with "Ctrl + Shift + R" on Windows, but it did not solve the problem.

I tried to modify the Internet Options > Privacy > Select a Setting for Internet Zone "High" (which blocks all cookies from websites that  do not have a compact privacy policy) and managed to reproduce the same behavior on my computer. But unfortunately, after asking the client, the client had his settings to "Medium" and not to "High". And I switched back to "Medium" on my computer, everything worked fine on my computer => so I don't know if there is a link.

**Do you have any hypothesis for why it does not work on IE?**
I am not looking for an exact answer but for several hypothesis and ideas on where it may come from.

Please find below some of my ideas:

1. Is it possible that the company network uses a proxy that remove the Set-Cookie header?
2. Is there a IE configuration that might prevent setting a login cookie?
3. I use a script for chat on my website called Chatra, and I had this on my console "SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://in.hotjar.com/api/v2/client/... required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) => do you think this is what prevents the login page from submitting correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could check IE 11 configuration about cookies from here:

[image]

If you want to enable cookies in IE, please make sure you have ticked 'Accept' of First-party and Third-party cookies and ticked the 'Always allow session cookies'.

Besides, hard refresh in IE is '**Ctrl + F5**'.

If others with the same version of IE and the same version of OS and the same network didn't have the issue, there might be something wrong with the user's IE browser. You could suggest the user to reset or reinstall his IE browser.

Reference:
(1) [How to reset Internet Explorer settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings)

(2) [How to reinstall or repair Internet Explorer in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318378/how-to-repair-or-reinstall-internet-explorer-in-windows)